# Infinite Loop in Java

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

So I'm trying to look at an input, and count words that fit a certain criteria (or rather, excluding words that I don't want to count). The error is in the following code:

```
    BufferedReader br;
    BufferedWriter bw;
    String line;
    int identifiers = 0;
    boolean count = false;

    try
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("A1.input"));
        line = br.readLine();

        while(line != null)
        {
            StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(line);
            String word;
            System.out.println(t.countTokens()); //for testing, keeps printing 6
            for(int c = 0; c < t.countTokens(); c++)
            {

                word = t.nextToken();
                count = true;
                if(Character.isDigit(word.charAt(0))) //if word begins with a number
                {
                    count = false; //do not count it
                } 
                if(count == true)
                {
                    for(String s : keywords)
                    {
                        if(s.equals(word)) //if the selected word is a keyword
                        {
                           count = false; //do not count it
                        }
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(word); //testing purposes

            }
            word = t.nextToken();
        }
```

Here is the input file:

```
INT f2(INT x, INT y ) 
  BEGIN 
  z := x*x - y*y;
RETURN z; 
 END 
 INT MAIN f1() 
 BEGIN
INT x;
READ(x, "A41.input");
INT y;
READ(y, "A42.input");
INT z;
z := f2(x,y) + f2(y,x);
WRITE (z, "A4.output"); 
END
```

As stated in the comments in the code above, the first println statement prints 6 repeatedly (indicating to me that the while loop is endlessly repeating). The second "testing purposes" println statement continuously prints `INT f2(INT x` repeatedly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're never actually reading the next line of the file. Change this bit:

```
try
{
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("A1.input"));
    line = br.readLine();

    while(line != null)
    {
```

to this:

```
try
{
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("A1.input"));

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
```

Comment: indeed
    line = br.readLine();
needs to found at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy: that would also work. What I suggested is just the paradigm I'm used to seeing, with the added bonus of being more concise to put into an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your use of `while()` is evaluating the current line only; thus, it's never `null`.  Change it to `if()`.